# Is there a way to check if I came from a specific activity before starting a new one?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Let's say I have 3 activities: `A`, `B`, and `C`. And all 3 activities can direct the user to one another. Is there a way to check if I came from a specific activity?

For example, to get to C, I can move from B -> C or A -> C. But is there a way for me to check if I came from B?

Comment: You can pass data in the intent when you navigate from one to another activity like you can search about putExtra and getExtra for passing data from one activity to another activity

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data payload through activity intent.pass your activity name for check where user came from.

start activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(yourFromActivity.this,yourToActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(bundle_key,yourActivityName);
startActivity(intent)
```

In your second activity check intent extra and get the activity name where user came from.

```
@override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

//check extra key has in bundle.should same as host activity key
   if(getIntent().hasExtra(bundle_key)) 
   {
       //get passed value from intent bundle
       String activity = getIntent().getStringExtra(bundle_key,"");

      if(activity.equel(yourActivityname)){
         //put logic here 
       }      

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by 2 ways which are

1. Pass extra parameter in Intent when calling activity and in receiver
   activity check received parameter and perform task accordingly.
2. Use startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity()  when calling
   activity & use getCallingActivity().getClassName() in receiver call to get
   class name.

Passing Data in Intent:

Calling class A:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this,C.class);
intent.putExtra("source","A");
startActivity(intent);
```

Receiver class C:
in onCreate method

```
String source;
Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent.hasExtra("source"))
{
 source = intent.getStringExtra("source");
}
//Now you received source class name you can check and perform action 
//accordingly.
if(source.equals("A")
{ 
 //For Class A
}
else{
  
 // For Class B
  }
```

Using startActivityForResult():

Sender Class:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(A.this,C.class);
 startActivityForResult(intent);
```

Receiver Class:

```
//In onCreate Method get calling activity name
 getCallingActivity().getClassName();
```

Answer (score -2):

**try this**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setClass(A.this,Receiveractivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Uniqid","From_Activity_A");  
A.this.startActivity(intent);

Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setClass(B.this,Receiveractivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Uniqid","From_Activity_B");  
B.this.startActivity(intent);

Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setClass(C.this,Receiveractivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Uniqid","From_Activity_C");  
C.this.startActivity(intent);
```

**Intent Activity**

```
//obtain  Intent Object send  from SenderActivity
Intent intent = this.getIntent();

/* Obtain String from Intent  */
if(intent !=null)
{
String strdata = intent.getExtras().getString("Uniqid");
if(strdata.equals("From_Activity_A"))
{
//Do Something here...
}
if(strdata.equals("From_Activity_B"))
{
//Do Something here...
}
if(strdata.equals("From_Activity_C"))
{
//Do Something here...
}
  ........
}
else
{
 //do something here
}
```